# Need my for loop to wait once my function return value till it go to next iteration

Tags: javascript

I am using a loop in my function which is calling another function I wanted it to wait till I get the result then go to next iteration.I am using promise but it is not working as well. Marked ** in that portion.

```
  function imagecheck(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            resolve('success');
        }
        img.onerror = function(){
            reject('failure');
        }
        img.src = url;
    });
}

function getcheck(Id) {
    var j=0;
    var myId = Id;
    var myimages = [];
    **for(var i=0;i<=j;i++)
   {
        var imageUrl = 'someprexixurl'+myId+'&page='+j;   
        this.imagecheck(imageUrl).then(function(successUrl){
            myimages.push({url:imageUrl});
            j++;
        }).catch(function(errorUrl){

            });
   }**
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do it in salesforce, I just kept the loop for only 25 times as per my requirement and I am setting total length of my completed array to 'counter' attribute. So, Basically when my getcheck function will be called it will give the result once imgArray have all the valid url's. Hope it will help others:

```
 imagecheck: function(url) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                resolve(url);
            }
            img.onerror = function(){
                reject('failure');
            }
            img.src = url;
        });
    },
    getcheck: function(component, callback) {
        var myId = component.get("v.currentversionobj").Id;
        var imgArr = [];
        var flag=0;
        for(var i=0; i<=25; i++) {
            var imageUrl = 'someprefixurl'+component.get("v.currentversionobj").Id+'&page='+i;   
            this.imagecheck(imageUrl).then(function(successUrl) {
                imgArr.push({url:successUrl}); 
                component.set("v.fileShares",imgArr);
            }).catch(function(errorUrl){
                flag=1;
            });        
        }
        var myVar = setInterval(function(){
            if(flag == 1){
                component.set("v.counter",imgArr.length);
                clearInterval(myVar);
                callback(true);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use async/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) to easily allow your loop to wait. Here's what that looks like:

```
async function getcheck(Id) {
    var j=0;
    var myId = Id;
    var myimages = [];
    for(var i=0;i<=j;i++)
    {
        try {
            var imageUrl = 'someprexixurl'+myId+'&page='+j;
            var data = await this.imagecheck(imageUrl);
            myimages.push({url:data});
            j++;
        } catch(e) {
            // Error handling here //
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! however I should have put this question in salesforce lightning context looks like async is not supported in lightning.

Comment: @Ruchit612 There should be a way. I'll see if I can write a demo.

Comment: Sure, However I have created a new question and put it in salesforce lightning context, If you get any answer you can put it there. Thank you.